# How to replace text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xhtml

There is large website all data comes from database ,

I want to remove all instances of "(MHC)" from next to company name on this page, and also more than 12 other pages.

like "**Northfield Bancorp Inc. (MHC)**" to "Northfield Bancorp Inc."

Is there any JavaScript for this?  I have tried [xslt solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003981/replacing-xml-value-in-xslt), but still prefer a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Sounds like someone is trying to rip off a corporate website design...

Comment: No Dear, I am working for that website. and got update from that Client, Thanks

Comment: Do this in client side JavaScript would be a very poor idea. The old data would still appear to users without JS, in search engine results, in browsers with JS while the page is being built, and so on.

Comment: Yes , you are right. Still thinking for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I'd just change the database entry...

Furthermore, you should be doing this removal on the server side. For example, you can use PHP to reformat the data before outputting it to the user. Simply use PHP to make the database query, store it in a PHP variable, and then parse the string appropriately.

Comment: Combine this answer with David Dorward's comment on the question and you have a perfect explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a replace:

```
var data = "Northfield Bancorp Inc. (MHC)";
var newData  = data.replace(" (MHC)", "", "ig");
```

Comment: You're right, but there doesn't exist a third parameter in replace. You'll need to convert it to a regular expression to make it work as excepted: / \\(MHC\\)/ig In this case, though, a global case-insensitive search is a bit of an overkill, since it works perfectly OK without it.

Comment: Well, 3rd parameter exists in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [javascript regular expressions](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-RegExp-Replace-String-Function.aspx) to parse your text