# Get specific part of string from xpath node without dashes

Tags: python, xpath

I use this

```
('//*[@class="book_details"]/text()[3]')
```

to grab the "ISBN 978-960-435-514-3, [some text here]"
but i want only the ISBN number without dashes"-" ("9789604355143")

```
<span class="book_details">
  2016
 <br>688 pages
 <br>ISBN 978-960-435-514-3, [some text here]
 <br>price
 <nobr> € 20,00</nobr>
</span>
```

Comment: If you can use xsl and you're limited to xpath 1 then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725370/is-there-a-way-to-emulate-correctly-replace-function-on-xpath-1.

Comment: Can `some text here` contain digits? Or is the ISBN the only part with digits?

Comment: ISBN is the only part with digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `translate(//*[@class="book_details"]/text()[3], translate(//*[@class="book_details"]/text()[3], '0123456789', ''), '')`. The inner `translate(//*[@class="book_details"]/text()[3], '0123456789', '')` finds all non-digits in the target node and the outer `translate` removes them.

Comment: My code is like this:`def parse_isbn(self, root):`
  `isbn = None`
  ` isbn_node = root.xpath(//*[@class="book_details"]/text()[3]) ` Im newbie, how to use translate?

Comment: Try `root.xpath("translate(//*[@class='book_details']/text()[3], translate(//*[@class='book_details']/text()[3], '0123456789', ''), '')")`.