# XSL. Evaluate expression

Tags: xslt, evaluate

Sorry for my English.

**XSL 1.0.** How can I to calculate expression from element or attribute value?

For example XML:

```
<position>
  <localizedName>ref-help</localizedName>
  <reference>concat('../help/', $lang, '/index.html')</reference>
</position>
```

I try use expression from 'reference' attribute:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/content/positions/position">
        <li>
          <!--Save expression to variable...-->
          <xsl:variable name="path" select="reference"/>
          <!--Evaluate variable and set it value to 'href'-->
          <a target="frDocument" href="{$path}">
            <xsl:variable name="x" select="localizedName"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$resources/lang:resources/lang:record[@id=$x]"/>
          </a>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

But I get string:

> **file:///C:/sendbox/author/application/support/concat('../help/',%20%24lang,%20'/index.html')**

How can I evaluate it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If your XSLT processor implements the [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/) extensions, you can reference [a function that dynamically evaluates strings as XPath expressions](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
  extension-element-prefixes="dyn"
>
  <xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="positions/position" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="position">
    <li>
      <a target="frDocument" href="{dyn:evaluate(reference)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="
          $resources/lang:resources/lang:record[@id=current()/localizedName]
        "/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note:

- there is no need to save things in a variable before using them
- there is a `current()` function you might have missed
- use `<xsl:apply-templates>` and `<xsl:template>` in favor of `<xsl:for-each>`

Comment: I use browsers (Internet Explorer 9, Google Chrome 18.0.1025.151 m and Safari 5.1.5). Expression 'dyn:evaluate' do not work in it. :(((

Comment: Then you are out of luck and must use a different approach. Evaluating strings as expressions is not built into XSLT. Have you thought about transforming on the server side?

Comment: Unfortunately these files are placed on local computers.

Comment: Unless you change some part of your approach, there is no way to do what you want to do. Not using XPath expressions in `<reference>` would be one of the ways to change your approach. Use `<reference>../help/$lang/index.html</reference>` and use some form of [XSLT string replacement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1005899/18771) to replace `"$lang"` with the value of `$lang`.