# Apply Templates to a node obtained from an XPATH variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm using XSLT 1.1 and I have an external document I am accessing like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="doc2URI" select="ancestor-or-self::book/@secondDoc"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document($doc2URI)"/>
```

What I'm trying to do is apply the template for a node in this document that is obtained by an XPath expression found in an XSLT variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="xpath">
  <xsl:call-template name="genPath"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

The `$xpath` variable for instance, could at one point in the code contain the result of: `/book[1]/title[1]`.

What I'd like to do is:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc2/$xpath"/>
```

But that doesn't work. If I go:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc2/book[1]/title[1]"/>
```

That does work, but there's no way I will know the exact XPath expression beforehand. It'll only be available through that `$xpath` variable.

My question is, how can I apply the template to that external document through the XPath expression contained in the `$xpath` variable?

Comment: It's very unlikely you are using XSLT 1.1 - that was a working draft published in 2001 and then abandoned. There were implementations but they either progressed to XSLT 2.0 (like Saxon) or disappeared off the face of the earth (like jd.xslt).

Comment: I think it might be 1.1. This is at the top of my stylesheet <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions"
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
 xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon"
 xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
 xmlns:xalanredirect="org.apache.xalan.xslt.extensions.Redirect"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:doc="http://nwalsh.com/xsl/documentation/1.0"
 version="1.1"
 exclude-result-prefixes="doc"
 extension-element-prefixes="saxon xalanredirect lxslt exsl">

Comment: You could write version="93.7" at the top of your stylesheet but that wouldn't make it conform to version 93.7 of the XSLT specification.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for `eval` for XSLT. This is al [XSLT 3.0 feature](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath).

In earlier versions you'll need an extension. See:

> [XSL. Evaluate expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046104/xsl-evaluate-expression)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't really shift everything to 3.0